# Placing vertices of graphs + wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have to draw graphs along with edges according to a file input by the user. I am using wxPython for the same.

Once the positions are clear I can easily create circles and edges between the nodes but
I have a problem that given a panel to draw on is there any way I can get to know optimum positions for the vertices to be if I know the number of vertices ?

By optimum I mean simply that its readable what has been drawn and written along with it.....

So say that I have to draw 3 vertices I just want that I am able to clearly get the coordinates of where to place the nodes and if I can make the system automated....

Please help ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a Graph Drawing algorithm. There is ongoing research in this area, but a simple force-directed algorithm can give good results for small graphs.  Look at [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29) article for the algorithm. You can also get some open source libraries that handle this problem, like [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) and [Graphvis](http://graphviz.org/).

Comment: In the wiki page that you given could you tell me what is timestep in the algorithm.... They have mentioned everything else but not that....

Comment: Hmm, it looks a bit strange.  Try section 2 in http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf

Comment: Also is there any library where I can use the inbuilt functions to get the node layout values but use my own functions to draw ?

Answer (score 0):

Also a good lib: [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/)

It offers a nice collection of layout algorithms

Comment: You can use the layout algorithms to create a Layout and then use the layout coords. [algorithms](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#layout-algorithms), [layout coords](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.5/python/igraph.layout.Layout-class.html#coords)